Data from second importrange function is in the wrong column
When I import 2 ranges that are each in Columns A to L in their respective sheets, the second range is being returned in Columns M to X.
How can I fix it so the data from both ranges is returned in Columns A to L one range below the other?
My current formula
=Query({
   importrange(
     "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaZ2ZJDRWZOLhgC7MEy9A88hJIxqE-zmfXb4JSzw2yw/edit?gid=801569922#gid=801569922",
     "Missions | RAW!A:L"),
   importrange(
     "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaZ2ZJDRWZOLhgC7MEy9A88hJIxqE-zmfXb4JSzw2yw/edit?gid=801569922#gid=801569922",
     "Authentication | RAW!A:L")},
   "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")


You are using a comma between the IMPORTRANGE functions, but should be using a semicolon.
                 -----------------
{{A,B}, {C,D}} = | A | B | C | D |
                 -----------------

                 ---------
{{A,B}; {C,D}} = | A | B |
                 ---------
                 | C | D |
                 ---------

So your formula should be:
=QUERY(
   { IMPORTRANGE(
       "1XAZ2ZJDRWZOLHGC7MEY9A88HJIXQE-ZMFXB4JSZW2YW",
       "Missions | RAW!A:L");
     IMPORTRANGE(
       "1XAZ2ZJDRWZOLHGC7MEY9A88HJIXQE-ZMFXB4JSZW2YW",
       "Authentication | RAW!A:L") },
   "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

Or equivalent
=LET(
  rng," | RAW!A:L",
  id,"1XAZ2ZJDRWZOLHGC7MEY9A88HJIXQE-ZMFXB4JSZW2YW", 
  QUERY(
   { IMPORTRANGE(id, "Missions"& rng);
     IMPORTRANGE(id, "Authentication"& rng) },
   "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"))


Please also note that if the sheets are in the same spreadsheet as the formula, you can use the following:
=Query(
   {"Missions | RAW!A:L";  "Authentication | RAW!A:L"},
   "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

